# Buttons in Horizontal Line Without Float:Left

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to display a row of links horizontally without using float:left? It's way too hard to center a div when using float:left, I can never get it to work.

Comment: "I can never get it to work." There's your real problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `display:inline;`

http://jsfiddle.net/tcQzL/3/

If your elements are inline elements they will display in one row, otherwise you must make them inline.

Comment: In inline element you can't define width, height, vertical margin & vertical padding.

Comment: Just wrap your elements into some parent div and use text-align:center ... See updated jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/tcQzL/9/

Answer (score 2):

you could try `display: inline` or `inline` depending on your needs (from what I know, inline-block offers more flexibility than just inline)

here, check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tcQzL/5/)

There's a catch though if you use these, if you look in the fiddle, my first two elements are written one after another so that I don't have any gaps between them (that's why I added the borders) and the other ones are written one below each other and as you can see, there's the gap I was talking about. So keep that in mind while writing your code.

There are different workarounds about this, but if you *do* need borders, and not just the text, you should really consider using `float` to avoid any workarounds

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add some divs around each link

Comment: In that way, div elements are display:block elements, you don't need inline-block anyway... Just inline :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but just make new `div`-where your buttons are in. And in that new `div` make your links have `float:left`
Then just normally position that new `div`you made.

But I think that those those earlier answers from Andrei S and mesiesta are more better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:inline-block` for that. Write like that

```
.link{
 display:inline-block;
 *display:inline;/* For IE7 */
 *zoom:1;/* For IE7 */
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/tcQzL/10/